# What's the best way to design an input that allows users to fill in exact answers but also estimated ones?

Tags: input-fields

For example, for a date field, users need to be able to input an exact date, but also must be able to input an estimated date (eg. " around 2024", "around Jan or Feb of 2024") if they are unsure of the exact date.

Comment: Please share as much as you can to improve the possibility to answer (correctly). Add context, what is it for, where is it needed, ideas you already have etc.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to split the date entry into year, month and date, with only year being mandatory. Or, it could be decade, year, and quarter.

In general,

1. Make the coarsest option, such as year or decade, as a mandatory input field, and
2. Make fine-grained choices optional, and nest them within the coarser choices.